# Exim permissions when sharing a dovecot mailfolder

Tags: debian, dovecot, exim

Using dovecot on debian wheezy, I have just set up a shared mailfolder inside another user's mail folder to be able to share the contents of this mailfolder with some other users, wthout duplicating incoming mails:

```
/var/mail/secretary/.shared.fax/
```

I then made a symlink inside my mailbox to this shared mailbox:

```
# ln -s /var/mail/secretary/.shared.fax-in /var/mail/vincent/.shared.fax
```

I set the permissions wide open to test this setup:

```
drwxrwsrwx  5 root  mail  4096 nov 28 15:38 .shared-fax
```

I was able to populate this folder from the Evolution mailclient using the shared folder, (which lead me to believe it was working), but then a new fax came in and was routed to this folder using an Exim 'forward-file':

```
if $header_from: contains "FaxMaster"
then
     save /var/mail/secretary/.shared-fax/
     finish
endif
```

Apparently, this messed up the permissions, because since then the mailclient allows me to see the amount of new emails in that folder, but not the new emails itself.

I presume this is caused by permissions, but I cannot find the right settings (I tried chowning folders and/or files to root/user, but to no avail - maybe I need some specific mix'n match permissions?) Thx!

Comment: How does exim set the permissions for the individual files in this directory?

Comment: You have to move all LDA functionality to the dovecot's `deliver`. Then MTA can know nothing about local mail permissions and owners. And you can restrict access to the local storage to the `600`

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are set by the `directory_mode` and `mode` settings in the `maildir_home` transport.  The `group` as well.

You may want to look at using a shared namespace in Dovecot to allow sharing the folder.